# Getting "compiled" HTML-page using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Page source code looks like this:

```
<td class="ftd">${row.time}</td>
<td class="mntd">${$item.getMTitle(row.movieId)}</td>
<td class="hntd" style="width:75px">${row.hall}</td>
<td class="ptd">${row.price}</td>
<td class="btd"><img class="butres" src="/image.png" alt=""/></td>
```

And the final code in the browser web-inspector looks like this:

```
<td class="ftd">Item1</td>
<td class="mntd">Item2</td>
<td class="hntd" style="width:75px">Item3</td>
<td class="ptd">Item4</td>
<td class="btd"><img class="butres" src="/image.png" alt=""></td>
```

I'm trying to parse web-page:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://domain.com/").timeout(0).get();
```

But it gets only source code. How can I get a "compiled" code?

Thanks.

Comment: Run it on the HTML produced by a server.

Comment: I want to get data from a remote server. There are variables in the source code of the page. There is a js-sctipt on the page that converts variables into the data. Here's a [screenshot](http://s24.postimg.org/9hg3igdwl/source.png).

Comment: In another words, I want to get and parse the **complete** page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you gave us the URL it'd be easier to help. jsoup doesn't execute JS (it's an HTML parser), which is why you're not seeing the data. My guess is that the data is coming in as json from an ajax request, using mustache.js as a template.

You can determine this by loading the page and looking at the network requests, using either your browser's network monitor, or a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Then you can use jsoup or another tool to fetch the data URL and a json parser to parse it.